# Overlaying <span> doesn't work in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<li>
  <span>overlay</span>
  content
</li>


li {
   position: relative;
   height:65px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
li span {
    background: url(../img/bullet_grey.png) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

This works in all browsers except IE6, which just hides the SPAN somewhere. How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: If I paste this code into an html document, the span is visible in IE6. Could you post html that actually replicates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [here](http://www.search-this.com/2007/11/08/look-whats-just-popped-up/) should guide you to the solution.